# What is the technique I need to know in order to develop "Chicken Pickin" for guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar, technique

Is there an established technique for Chicken Pickin on guitar or is it more like a technique that guitar players develop for themselves just by experimenting with their instruments? I'd like a description of technique and some possible variations that I might fool with in order develop my own skills in this area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say there *is* a generally established core technique that I'd teach via hybrid picking, but you'll find a lot of notable players have all developed their own mechanisms both for the actual chicken pickin' and for the transitions in and out of the technique.

Two artists that spring to mind as having clearly communicated and demonstrated their approach to chicken pickin' as well as showing some licks based around it are Johnny Hiland and Greg Koch.

[Greg Koch example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4j8sZECmVE)

[Johnny Hiland example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asxwPIil5lQ)